# NestJS Streaming Files technique not working

Tags: typescript, rest, csv, streaming, nestjs

I am trying to stream CSV file using [NestJS Streaming Files technique](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/streaming-files), but the request seems to be stuck. Am I missing something here?

Sample code snippet:

```
import {StreamableFile} from '@nestjs/common';
import * as fs from 'fs';

@Get('csv')
csvStream(
  @Req() req: Request,
  @Res() res: Response,
): StreamableFile {
  const file = 'test.csv';
  const readStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
  readStream.on('data', (chunk) => console.log(chunk));  <--- the data log gets printed
  readStream.on('finish', () => console.log('done'));
  return new StreamableFile(readStream);
}
```

The data log gets printed (check statement - `readStream.on('data', (chunk) => console.log(chunk))`), and output is similar to below:

```
<Buffer 23 4a 45 67 11 97 ... 1022 more bytes>
```

and the request stays stuck in this state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following worked for me, locally...

```typescript
import { Controller, Get, Req, Response, StreamableFile } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';

@Controller()
export class FileController {
    @Get('csv')
    csvStream(@Req() req, @Response({ passthrough: true }) res): StreamableFile {
        res.set({
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });

        const file = path.join(__dirname, 'test.csv');
        const readStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
        readStream.on('data', (chunk) => console.log(chunk)); // <--- the data log gets printed
        readStream.on('end', () => console.log('done'));
        readStream.on('error', (err) => { console.error(err); });

        return new StreamableFile(readStream);
    }
}
```

Please mind the `{ passthrough: true }`. That's what made me get a response, so seems quite important!!!

Comment: Hi @Nalin Ranjan, `{ passthrough: true }` allowed request to pass, but it did not return any csv rows.

Comment: How large is the csv file? Also, in browser, it got downloaded as a file, mostly because of `content-type` header.

Comment: I have included `content-type` header in the answer. And I tried with only few bytes in csv. How large is your file?

Comment: I was hoping for csv rows as output, not file (I am using postman for making request). Is there a way to achieve this (without using `pipe`)?. If not, i don't think NestJS Streaming solution (https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/streaming-files) is helpful for my use case

Comment: I got why is your `finish` event not working. Actually, `finish` is there on WritableStream, whereas this one is a `ReadableStream`, Try with `end` event...instead of `on('finish', ...)`, try `on('end', ...)`... Have updated in the answer in case you need it.

Comment: [ReadableStream](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/stream.html#class-streamreadable) API on Nodejs documentation for reference.

Comment: For the `csv rows and not file`, you will have to set an appropriate `content-type` header. in my answer, I have included it as `text/plain`, but you can very well set it to any other supported value.

Comment: @Nalin what can we do with the result of the function " return new StreamableFile(readStream); " ?  a front for example how it will process it ?

Comment: I'm not really satisfied by this answer

As per the Nest.js documentation, unless it has an error, it shows an example without passtrhough



  `@Get()
  @Header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  @Header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="package.json"')
  getStaticFile(): StreamableFile {
    const file = createReadStream(join(process.cwd(), 'package.json'));
    return new StreamableFile(file);
  } `

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/streaming-files

Answer (score 1):

`{ passthrough: true }` is required because `StreamableFile` is a custom object, so you need to explicitly pass it on to the next middleware -- it is not responsible for sending the response to the client.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this issue myself. The problem lies in using `@Res()` because when you use `@Res()` handler you should handle the response yourself: you cannot just return some object, you have to use `res.send()` or some alternative method